# Replicate html state in a android native way

Tags: android, html, json

Let's say I have an `HTML` page which has `CSS` bound, all parsed from `JSON` `data`; is there a way to reproduce exactly ( with responsivity as well ) the same visualization in an `android` `application` with no `webview` ? 
My goal is to have a `html` product that I can see also on an `application`, but with native elements.

**EDIT**

maybe this semplifies the situation: how to share `HTML` between mobile and web?

Comment: You want to display html in android app?

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: the problem is sharing html between mobile and web

Comment: It's not just a HTML.It's HTML , state and the css which I think you said as responsive. That's why I said not possible.

Comment: Ok, can you be a little bit more explicative?

Answer (score -2):

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(HTML_STRING));
```

Comment: textView does not support all the html tags.they are limited.and the css also not supported in TextView.

Comment: textView was just an example, other android components can also be used.